# How To use inner Join with two table where one table has id in array ["11", "12"]

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table promos - which has contract table id like ["11,"12"]

Table contract - which has id reference name.

I am trying to get the name from contract table with below sql query but showing error in query

SELECT * FROM promos INNER JOIN contract ON  promos.contracts_id=contract.id
[image: contract]
[image: promos]

Expected Result
[image: expected table]

Please suggest, how to get this type of ID with query without change IN TABLE.

Comment: it is never a good idea to store foreign keys in this way. read about normalization

Comment: Use JSON_CONTAINS() in ON clause, for example. Or any other searching JSON function. But the best solution is to normalize your data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query (match records using `JSON_CONTAINS` and after this group them using `JSON_ARRAYAGG`:

```
SELECT contracts_ids, JSON_ARRAYAGG(name)
FROM promos 
LEFT JOIN contract ON JSON_CONTAINS(contracts_ids, CONCAT('"', contract.id, '"'))
GROUP BY promos.id, contracts_ids;
```

[Online SQL editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/8acca83c2823b510f63cdc6a6413736d/)